# How to safely share data between 2 SPAs?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, http, man-in-the-middle, web

Let's say I have 2 SPAs (single page applications), SPA A and SPA B.

I want to share data between the 2 applications for an end-to-end flow.

How can I safely share data such that it would not be susceptible to a MITM attack. Even if the data is encrypted and it is passed via POST, it could still be generated by a different client and then a victim could be dropping into the middle of the end-to-end flow.

e.g.

1. SPA A (Attacker) -> finds out what data is passed to SPA B via POST/GET/etc.
2. Victim gets redirected to SPA B via Attacker's website with data from SPA A.
3. Victim now did not complete the steps in SPA A but is dropped in to SPA B via MITM.

We can't check referrers because they are not reliable (Referrer-Policy no-referrer). We could use a whitelist but that is challenging if you have many different legitimate clients that direct to SPA B in the middle of the flow. We could drop a client cookie and include it in the data that gets sent to SPA B and then verify it doesn't change end-to-end.

Is there a more standardized way to take care of this situation to determine it's the same user end-to-end or check the referrer to make sure it wasn't a MITM?

Comment: *"redirected to SPA B via Attacker's website with data from SPA A"* - What do you mean by this? How can the attacker's web site the user's data from SPA A?

Comment: @mentallurg since the data is passed between the SPAs via GET params in plain sight even though it's encrypted, it's still passed in a way that anyone could act as a MITM, or is there a better way to pass it that would solve this?

Comment: To be clear, let's say I am the attacker on SPA A, I just get the URL that would go to SPA B then client redirect 302 the victim when they are on my site then it seems like they did the whole flow but the user actually changed..

Comment: OP, typically we use digital signatures to authenticate data.  You might want to consider using client-side (in browser) crypto (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API) to have user A sign the data that gets passed from SPA A to SPA B, using the user A's keypair.  Then, user B at SPA B can verify the signature using user A's public key.  This would thwart a MITM attack, as any attempt by a MITM to modify the data would break the signature.  You just need a way for user B to authenticate user A's public key, but this can be done using a trusted CA.

Comment: 1) *"passed in a way that anyone could act as a MITM"* - This is only possible if you use HTTP. If you use HTTPS, MITM is not possible.

Comment: 2) May be you think that if you see GET parameters in browser URL field, also anyone can see? If you use HTTPS, this is not possible. In HTTPS request only host name and port are not encrypted. Everything else is encrypted. For instance, if you send a GET request to `https://example.com/app-A/service?user=123&order=456`, the part `/app-A/service?user=123&order=456` will be encrypted. Nobody between browser and your server will be able to decrypt it.

Comment: 3) *"then client redirect 302 the victim"* - Only the server can redirect. Do you mean, the attacker owns your server and responses with HTTP 302 to some request?

Comment: 4) Please explain the attack scenario. It is still not clear. Do you mean, the attacker uses XSRF to make user of the SPA A click on a link that pints to server of the SPA B? Or you mean the attacker is a legitimate user of SPA A and calls the server of the SPA B? Or something else?

Comment: 5) *"SPA A (Attacker) -> finds out what data is passed to SPA B via POST/GET/etc."* - If HTTPS is used, this is impossible. If some of these data identify the user, e.g. session ID or authentication token, and the user allows the attacker to look over the shoulder and see these data, then it is problem of the user. It is like showing your password to somebody else.

Comment: @mentallurg the Attacker goes on SPA A and gets a URL with encrypted data, then the Victim visits the Attacker's site, and the Attacker 302 redirects the Victim to SPA B. It seems User A was the one who went end-to-end from SPA A to SPA B, but it was really the Attacker then the Victim.

Comment: @mti2935 where do the keys for the users come from, the browser? So basically it's a unique key associated with the client that can be used to encrypt/decrypt on client-side?

Comment: *"the Attacker goes on SPA A and gets a URL with encrypted data"* - In the SAP A the attacker can see see only own data. Nobody can see data from any other users. If HTTPS is used, traffic cannot be read. That's why it is not clear, how the attacker can obtain any data. Please explain how the attacker gets data in your scenario.

Comment: If you mean the attacker intercepted the encrypted traffic and later on resends it, it will not work, because HTTPS makes reply impossible.

Comment: OP,  Yes, each client has a unique private/public keypair, and encryption takes place on the client-side, 'in browser' (using javascript).  There are a number of ways that keys can be stored and managed by the client in such a system.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/247918/need-some-clarification-regards-end-to-end-encryption-process for more info.

Comment: OP, When you say '*the Attacker goes on SPA A*', do you mean the attacker gains access to the user's device that has SPA A runnng in the web browser?  Or, to you mean that the attacker gains access to the server that serves the files that comprise SPA A?

Comment: @mti2935 the exploit is because the Victim should be going through SPA A -> SPA B end-to-end but the Attacker generates data at SPA A on their own via their own client, then drops the Victim into SPA B using the data they generated when Victim visits their site by doing a 302 re-direct, making it seem to the Victim like the flow started at SPA B with the data pre-filled.

Comment: OP, After reading this question, and the ensuing comments several times, I think what you are concerned about is the user posting information to the SPA B server, before completing the requisite steps with the SPA A server (possibly because of interference by an attacker).  Is that correct?  If so, then this can be designed such that the post data that the SPA A server provides to the client to POST to the SPA B server is timestamped and unique for each instance, and signed (or HMAC'd) by the SPA A server such that the SPA B server can authenticate that it actually came from SPA A.

Comment: @mti2935 yes, that is right, although I'm not sure it would be possible if it was a POST because CSRF protection would prevent the Attacker from being able to POST to SPA B from another site.. but yes regardless you have the idea. The thing is that we are already using crypto on Node.js layer to encrypt the data.. so it's encrypted.. so it IS coming from SPA A.. it's just 2 different users and that is the problem.

Comment: I could include a unique client identifier like a cookie or something on the client and the encrypted data and then make sure it is the same client when decrypting again but that seems like overkill I was hoping there is a more canonical solution..

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of back and forth in the comments with OP and [@mentallurg](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/47524/mentallurg), this question finally makes sense.  OP has a system where the user starts some process at SPA A, then SPA A causes the user's browser to make a GET request to the server hosting SPA B, in order to redirect the user to SPA B, where the user completes the process.  Information from the user's session with SPA A is included in this GET request, so that this information is transferred from SPA A to SPA B.

OP wants to ensure that the user actually starts the process at SPA A first, before completing the process at SPA B.  This is to thwart an attack where an attacker starts the process at SPA A, then lures the user to the attacker's site (perhaps by phishing), then uses a 302 redirect to cause the user to make the same GET request to SPA B that the attacker would have made had the attacker completed the process himself.  By doing this, the attacker dupes to the user into completing the second step of the process at SPA B, using information that the attacker 'planted' in the first step of the process at SPA A.

[Note:  Part of the confusion around this question stems from the use of terms like 'MITM' and 'end-to-end' in ways that these terms are not normally used in information security.]

OP mentions the use of cookies as a possible solution.  In general, a cookie can only be read by the same domain that set it.  This is part of [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).  So, if SPA A sets a cookie, SPA B would not be able to read the cookie.  There is good reason for this - cookies often store sensitive information that users to not want to share with other sites.  In other words, browsers try to prevent you from doing exactly what you are trying to do.  However, there are some <s>hacks</s> workarounds to get around this, if it's possible for SPA A page to include some content from the domain that serves SPA B.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761415/how-to-set-a-cookie-for-another-domain for some ideas around this.

As another way of getting around this, some sites use [browser fingerprinting](https://www.eff.org/pages/cover-your-tracks) to track users from site to site.  But, this is considered controversial, and is not recommended.

Perhaps a simple and non-invasive solution is to simply to ask the user for some secret that an attacker would not know when the user starts the process at SPA A (e.g. 'what city were you born in?').  Then, cryptographically tangle this secret in the GET request that takes the user from SPA A to SPA B.  Then, ask the user to provide the same secret when he gets to SPA B, then verify that this secret is the one tangled in the GET request.