# How can I encrypt files securely in my website?

Tags: encryption, web, cloud-storage

With Django, I'm doing a file transfer website. One use will upload a file and then the recipient will download the file.

I want to encrypt this file securely so that the encryption key is not stored on the server.

I understand how end-to-end encryption works, but I can't achieve this with a Django website since you need to store a private key on a device (websites can't do this, unless you know a way to do this).

It must not be password based (that is a premium feature in my website).

One solution I have thought of is storing the encryption key in the URL since anyone that has access to the URL has access to the file anyway. Is this secure?

How can I encrypt a file when it is uploaded to the server, then somehow decrypt the same file in the recipients end without having to store the encryption key.

Comment: You might want to consider using the [Web Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API) to do file encryption in-browser, using client-side scripting.  See https://www.encryptedsend.com/ for a project similar to the one you describe (FD, I am the developer).  With regard to storing/managing keys, see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/247918/need-some-clarification-regards-end-to-end-encryption-process.

Comment: This is the same question you've asked today.