# What is risks model for a keys container implementation for web page in browser

Tags: web-application

I consider myself a newbie into security.
Standard questions for Kagi search was not helpful this time, so I come here in hope for answers.

I thinking about implementing a web app,like end-to-end-encrypted messaging application.

Expected functionality require saving a set keys in an encrypted entries of IndexedDB.

Master encryption key is planned to be derived with PBKDF2 and to be is used to wrap a real encryption key for rest of IndexedDB contents, including other saved (wrapped) keys:

1. local private key for signing messages (this message is from user Alice, not from Bob or Charlie),
2. auth keys for HMAC (in hope to prevent data tampering in transit),
3. signed ECDH pairs map for future async connections (heard Signal use something like that, to allow async connections),
4. AES-256-GCM keys encrypting local messages history.
5. material to re-derive next encryption keys for messages to be sent in active discussions.

Master encryption key parameters and password is [user + device] specific.

Actually, it is an implementation of keys container functionality, as I see.

That is why I asking about risk model exactly of "keys container" in a page of web browser.
Placing it under a "web worker" does not change too much, I assume?

Thanks for your answers and time.

## Update

Added few restrictions to context
After reviewed links mentioned to context, I decided to clarify context a bit. Lets assume that implementation is run in a page with following additional parameters:

- CSP is enabled, only content from single app-related origin allowed - scripts, styles, images, media.
- Resources integrity attributes on scripts and styles applied.
- Application is designed in a way that no third-party scripts are running - no analytics, advertisements, payments-related-scripts, share buttons, or other third-party scripts running, even from third-party CDN or such.
- All input from users sanitized, to prevent "even unintentional" JS injection.

I understand that user can open dev tools and scrap anything or inject anything. I also aware that user can have a crappy dangerous browser extension that will compromise anything or . But is there is any detailed risks model beyond that for context provided?

PS: "scrap anything" literally means e. g. assigning new `generateKey` like

```
crypto.subtle.generateKey = () => Promise.resolve();
```

to intercept keys at moment of generation. It can be used to generate keys as extractable, sending generated keys to attacker, and than - to prevent suspicion - re-import exported keys to set proper `extractable` flag, same as it was in the "original" call parameters.

Essentially, it means that web, even being popular, is not designed (yet) to support a more or less "trustworthy" environment for E2EE apps. But web is what we have, unless such apps are intentionally written native, where still other kinds of risks present.

Only implementing native named key containers can improve that a bit, but the implementation must be well protected, including from tricks like shown above.

Comment: Related: [Where and how to store private keys in web applications for private messaging with web browsers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35530/where-and-how-to-store-private-keys-in-web-applications-for-private-messaging-wi/52488) and [Need some clarification regards end-to-end encryption process](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/247918/need-some-clarification-regards-end-to-end-encryption-process)

Comment: @mti2935 Yes, these questions are related. I already seen them before. I will clarify the details a bit now.